# Flutter widget preview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, android-widget, preview

Let's suppose i am debugging an already built app and i needed to see the widget/screen and how it looks(without running the application and going through all the different screens to reach the desired one)  ,
i know there is an annotation (@preview) in jetpack compose for native android to preview the widget in question isolated from the whole app ,
in the meantime to preview a certain widget i put it in

```
void main() => runApp(ParticularScreen());
```

is there any other option ?
ps : i think there is a plugin for vs code called preview
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jamesblasco.flutter-preview
i am looking for exactly the same but with android studio